# CreateProcessAsUserW processes not searching PATH

Tags: java, c++, windows, winapi, jna

My goal is to run processes in the same way you'd run them in `cmd.exe`. For example:

```
C:\Users\zjoseal\Desktop>whoami.exe
ant\zjoseal
```

This works because `cmd.exe` searches for `whoami.exe` in the search path. I will also need environment variable evaluation.

I also need to execute the process as different users, so I'm forced to use the Windows API's [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) instead of Java's simple [`Runtime::exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-) or [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Unfortunately, this API function isn't offering me the command-line interpreter features I mentioned above. When I run `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c whoami.exe > whoami.txt`, I get:

```
'whoami.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It's only when I run `"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\whoami.exe > whoami.txt"` (note the absolute path for `whoami`) that my program works.

**Note that `whoami` is just an example program.** I need to run any given command as if it were being run on the command line.

What do I need to do in order to get the full command-line experience? According to the [`CreateProcessAsUserW` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw), if I pass `NULL` to `lpEnvironment`, the new process inherits the environment of the calling process, so the PATH should be getting inherited.

Here is the main part of my code:

```java
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow
final STARTUPINFOW.ByReference startupInfoW =
    new STARTUPINFOW.ByReference();
startupInfoW.cb = startupInfoW.size();
startupInfoW.lpReserved = Pointer.NULL;
startupInfoW.lpDesktop = Pointer.NULL;
startupInfoW.lpTitle = Pointer.NULL;
startupInfoW.dwFlags
    = startupInfoW.dwX = startupInfoW.dwY
    = startupInfoW.dwXSize = startupInfoW.dwYSize
    = startupInfoW.dwXCountChars = startupInfoW.dwYCountChars
    = startupInfoW.dwFillAttribute
    = startupInfoW.wShowWindow
    = 0;
startupInfoW.cbReserved2  = 0;
startupInfoW.lpReserved2 = Pointer.NULL;
startupInfoW.hStdInput = startupInfoW.hStdOutput
    = startupInfoW.hStdError
    = Pointer.NULL;
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information
final PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference processInformation =
    new PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference();
processInformation.hProcess = processInformation.hThread
    = Pointer.NULL;
processInformation.dwProcessId = processInformation.dwThreadId
    = 0;
// Converts string to char array with 0 as last element.
final char[] whoamiCmd = toCString(
    "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c whoami.exe > whoami.txt"
);
System.out.printf(
    "last err code = %d\n",
    ErrHandlingApi.INSTANCE.GetLastError()
);
final boolean createProcessOk = MyProcessThreadsApi.INSTANCE
    .CreateProcessAsUserW(
        userPrimaryToken.getValue(),
        Pointer.NULL,
        whoamiCmd,
        Pointer.NULL,
        Pointer.NULL,
        false,
        WinBase.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        new PointerByReference(),
        Pointer.NULL,
        startupInfoW,
        processInformation
    );
System.out.printf(
    "last err code = %d\n",
    ErrHandlingApi.INSTANCE.GetLastError()
);
System.out.printf("ok = %b\n", createProcessOk);
System.out.printf(
    "dwProcessId = %d\n", processInformation.dwProcessId
);
```

```java
public static char[] toCString(final String str) {
    final char[] cString = new char[str.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        cString[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }
    // c-strings end in 0 for lack of bounds checking
    cString[cString.length-1] = 0;
    return cString;
}
```

```
C:\Users\zjoseal\Desktop>java -cp windows-credentials-poc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Main
last err code = 0
last err code = 0
last err code = 0
last err code = 0
my-password
ptr.peer = 0
last err code = 0
last err code = 0
ok = true
ptr.peer = 1052
last err code = 0
last err code = 5
ok = true
dwProcessId = 8936

C:\Users\zjoseal\Desktop>'whoami.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: exec cmd is senseless. direct run whoami.exe

Comment: And also [redirect its output using the STARTUPINFO struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) so you can capture the output yourself, and then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: In your Java code, check that `System.getenv("PATH")` is reporting the correct path environment you are expecting.

Comment: As the link says `CreateProcessAsUserW ` - _"...The function will not use the search path..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, it does. However, under `lpCommandLine` it says "the system searches for the executable file in the following sequence:... 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable". It is at least a little confusing ;-)

Comment: @Christian.K you and Richard are both right:  it ignores PATH but it does have a set of directories that it searches. But that same paragraph indicates it uses "the first whitespace delimited token" which in the above case is the cmd.exe.  Which is executing just fine.  You don't need the path for cmd.exe in this example but you do need the path to the argument if it's not in the current directory.

Comment: @RbMm whoami.exe is just an example. I need to run any given command as another user. If I directly run it, I'll get the same issue.

Comment: @RichardCritten right, I'm not implying that the function is misbehaving. However, how do I get around the fact that it doesn't do a path search for all of the arguments?

Comment: @JoséAlvaradoTorre if you directly run it, you don't need the path if it's in one of the directories listed under the `lpCommandLine` heading.

Comment: @JoséAlvaradoTorre it does not search PATH. It searches a specific set of directories.  To use the PATH you need to use the `ShellExecute` function which is part of AXE and isn't really easy to do from Java.

Comment: @DanielWiddis is there a version of `ShellExecute` that lets me run the process as another user?

Comment: @JoséAlvaradoTorre -  *I need to run any given command as another user* - and never for this need invoke *cmd* - run "command" (ie some exe) direct.

Comment: What is the reason you cannot just use the full path?

Comment: @JoséAlvaradoTorre "*is there a version of ShellExecute that lets me run the process as another user?*" - not directly, only `CreateProcessAsUser()` can do that. `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `runas` verb can run as an elevated admin under UAC, but that is all. Otherwise, you would have to impersonate the desired user before calling `ShellExecute()`

Comment: @DanielWiddis RbMm this weird requirement comes from the fact that we already support this for Linux. We're building a platform that runs user code. They should be able to define a Windows command to run under a user they specify separately.

Comment: dont know about linux, but `L"whoami.exe"` in command line is run ok. even `L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c whoami.exe > whoami.txt"` is run ok. search path is used. need look binary for understand why your code fail. and in general case - are you have `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` ?

Comment: and in any case - in linux think not exist cmd.exe at all. not exist CreateProcessAsUserW, etc. so anyway need run exe direct without cmd shim

Comment: @RbMm Did you try that on the command line or the CreateProcessAsUser function? What does the `L` in `L"whoami.exe"` do? I remember having to add the assign primary token right to my user in order to get this working.

Comment: @JoséAlvaradoTorre - *Did you try that on the command line or the CreateProcessAsUser function?* - of course and this is work ok. with both cmd and direct (much more better), `L` this is only *c/c++* syntax mean unicode string

Comment: @RbMm Linux is a totally different story. We optionally use a different command-line interpreter, and we can just use `sudo` to run as a different user.

Comment: @RbMm That's surprising! What other arguments did you pass to CreateProcessAsUserW? Do you see a difference between the ones I passed and the ones you passed?

Comment: `new PointerByReference()` is your error in place `lpEnvironment`

Comment: Oh wow! After changing the parameter to `Pointer` type and assigning `Pointer.NULL`, it succeeded! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a nuanced discussion in the comments about the behavior of [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) in case someone is interested.

However, the reason `C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c whoami.exe > whoami.txt` wasn't working is that I was incorrectly passing the `lpEnvironment` argument. Instead of passing `new PointerByReference()`, I should has passed `Pointer.NULL`. This required changing the parameter type of my JNA function to `Pointer` instead of `PointerByReference`.